# How to pass tuple as argument in Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Suppose I want a list of tuples. Here's my first idea:

```
li = []
li.append(3, 'three')
```

Which results in:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./foo.py", line 12, in <module>
    li.append('three', 3)
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

So I resort to:

```
li = []
item = 3, 'three'
li.append(item)
```

which works, but seems overly verbose. Is there a better way?

Comment: Hope that the following link will bring some light to you in about how to work with tuples: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm

Comment: @Artsiom Rudzenka - That tutorial is dangerous :( Not only does it have mistakes like mixing lists and tuples, it shows silly things like ending lines with `;` for some reason.

Comment: @viraptor yes, you are right, it is always better to use official python tutorial: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences

Comment: Earlier versions of Python did convert the append(arg,...) syntax into append((arg,...)) automatically. They took it out because it added confusion. Old books would show your example as working. This is why it is best to check the documentation on the Python.org site or your installed Python distribution.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Add more parentheses:

```
li.append((3, 'three'))
```

Parentheses with a comma create a tuple, unless it's a list of arguments.

That means:

```
()    # this is a 0-length tuple
(1,)  # this is a tuple containing "1"
1,    # this is a tuple containing "1"
(1)   # this is number one - it's exactly the same as:
1     # also number one
(1,2) # tuple with 2 elements
1,2   # tuple with 2 elements
```

A similar effect happens with 0-length tuple:

```
type() # <- missing argument
type(()) # returns <type 'tuple'>
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out explicitly that `(1)` is NOT a tuple. A pair of parentheses in that case is parsed for other syntax meanings (for order and precedence in math evaluations?).  The syntax is different from `[1]` where it is a list.

Answer (score 8):

It's because that's *not* a tuple, it's two arguments to the `add` method. If you want to give it *one* argument which is a tuple, the argument itself has to be `(3, 'three')`:

```
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Apr 16 2010, 13:09:56) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> li = []

>>> li.append(3, 'three')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

>>> li.append( (3,'three') )

>>> li
[(3, 'three')]

>>>
```

Answer (score 6):

Parentheses used to define a tuple are optional in return and assignement statements. i.e:

```
foo = 3, 1
# equivalent to
foo = (3, 1)

def bar():
    return 3, 1
# equivalent to
def bar():
    return (3, 1)

first, second = bar()
# equivalent to
(first, second) = bar()
```

in function call, you have to explicitely define the tuple:

```
def baz(myTuple):
    first, second = myTuple
    return first

baz((3, 1))
```

Comment: This helped me. I also found you can unpack earlier, eg `def baz((first, second)):`

Comment: Only if you are stuck in Python 2.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035591/python-cant-define-tuples-in-a-function

Answer (score 0):

it throws that error because list.append only takes one argument

try this
list += ['x','y','z']

Answer (score 0):

```py
def product(my_tuple):
    for i in my_tuple:
        print(i)

my_tuple = (2,3,4,5)
product(my_tuple)
```

**This how you pass Tuple as an argument**

Comment: While this is completely true, this what the OP initially used which is very verbose. I'd suggest to elaborate on this and add some more information on applying this on the OP's problem with a list to improve your answer