# Round Bracket inside Round Bracket in Def Function

Tags: python

I am doing a pygame physics tutorial. However, when I try putting Round Bracket inside Round Bracket in Def Function, it says "Invalid Syntax". I could not find a answer anywhere.

```
def addVectors((angle1, length1), (angle2, length2)):
```

Comment: Why is it so critical to have that particular syntax?

Comment: Because of `(self.angle, self.speed) = addVectors((self.angle, self.speed), gravity)`

Comment: *"I could not find a answer anywhere"* - answer to what? I can't see a question... You show a wrong syntax you wrote. Why do you expect it to work? What do you ***expect*** it to do?

Comment: @Tomerikoo   Turns out it only works in python 2.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python can't define tuples in a function (duplicate)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20035591/6045800)

Comment: Yes, but someone already answered it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That only works in Python 2 sadly:

```
>$ python2
Python 2.7.18 (default, Mar  8 2021, 13:02:45) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def addVectors((angle1, length1), (angle2, length2)):
...   pass
... 
>>> 
>$ python3
Python 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 19:58:26) 
[GCC 7.3.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def addVectors((angle1, length1), (angle2, length2)):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def addVectors((angle1, length1), (angle2, length2)):
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I suggest using a `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Vector = namedtuple('Vector', ['angle', 'length'])

v1 = Vector(angle=1, length=1)
v2 = Vector(angle=2, length=1)

def addVectors(v1, v2):
    return Vector(v1.angle + v2.angle, v1.length + v2.length)
```

Comment: oh. Thats unfortunate.

Comment: @ChinDaMay added a suggestion for an alternative

Comment: the implementation of the vector sum is wrong, it is just to give you an idea of how to use the `namedtuple`

Comment: You really don't need to make up a separate type for this. Just unpack the parameters on the first line.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes of course, it depends on personal preference in the end. the unpacking at the start is also a reasonable option

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to pass a tuple by parameter but this way is the wrong syntax way. Try something like that:

```
def addVectors(*angles):
    for i in angles:
        print(i)

# addVectors((angle1, length1), (angle2, length2))
# (1, 2)
# (3, 4)
```

The * will unpack like a list and you can pass any size of parameters

Comment: How would I Integrate that with: `def addVectors(angle1, length1, angle2, length2):
  x = math.sin(angle1)*length1 +math.sin(angle2)*length2
  y = math.cos(angle1)*length1 +math.cos(angle2)*length2
  angle = 0.5*math.pi -math.atan2(y,x)
  length = math.hypot(x,y)
  return(angle, length)`

Comment: Thats is another question!

Answer (score 1):

Given your specific example, you can hopefully see why the syntax you are looking for is error prone. Imagine what happens when you accidentally mess up a single parenthesis 6 months from now. You have a couple of options to implement the same functionality trivially in Python 3 with fewer parentheses.

If you want the input to be four objects:

```
def addVectors(angle1, length1, angle2, length2):
    ...
```

and call as

```
self.angle, self.speed = addVectors(self.angle, self.speed, *gravity)
```

If you want two inputs, you can specify an explicit unpacking:

```
def addVectors(vector1, vector2):
    angle1, length1 = vector1
    angle2, length2 = vector2
    ...
```

and call it as

```
self.angle, self.speed = addVectors((self.angle, self.speed), gravity)
```

As you can see, there's no reason to give up on Python 3 just because of this syntax.